Automatically mount a per-user drive on login with systemd
I have a NAS which provides SMB/CIFS shares and I've also just set up a new PC (running EndeavourOS/Arch) and want to automatically mount those shares. In the past I've always handled this by simply using systemd mount units to mount my shares at boot, but since this is a multi-user system and each user has their own NAS credentials and private shares, this obviously isn't feasable here.
My goal is to have each user be able to access their private share on login, ideally in a way where they can freely choose a different mountpoint in their home directory without needing superuser access to modify it, but so far nothing I've tried has worked.
Systemd provides userspace units but those can't mount anything that's not already defined in fstab (and I don't really want to use fstab if I can avoid it, the systemd units are much more readable and maintainable imo). I've thought about simply creating a "normal" system-wide mount unit for each user in conjunction with a corresponding automount unit, but that feels like a pretty inelegant solution.
Is there a "nice" way to actually do this? The whole "user can change the mountpoint to somewhere else in their home dir" would be nice but isn't required.


ideally in a way where they can freely choose a different mountpoint in their home directory without needing superuser access to modify it,

The easiest way to accomplish this is by not mounting anything underneath the user's home directory. Mount the shares somewhere like /nas/<user> and create a symlink in the user's home, which they can move or replace in whatever way they want.
And if the user really wants a mountpoint, they can use e.g. 9bind (which is just a setuid mount --bind) or some similar approach.
There are various small disadvantages to placing mounts underneath $HOME; e.g. performance problems with file manager apps that try to descend into what looks like an ordinary directory; or encrypted home directories such as via eCryptFS or via systemd-homed, which won't be able to umount the home directory if something else is mounted underneath.

Having all mounts under /nas will also help with the next suggestion, which is to use autofs for all mountpoints. The autofs daemon uses the same kernel facility as systemd .automount units, but it natively supports an "indirect" mode (which is in fact the default) where it would be enough to define just one entry
For example, in my environment with multiple hosts acting as NFS servers (and each server accessible through /net/<name>), I have:
ember -nfsvers=4,proto=tcp,soft,nosuid,nodev,sec=krb5i &.example.com:/
*     -nfsvers=4,proto=tcp,soft,nosuid,nodev,sec=krb5p &.example.com:/

...which will result in the autofs daemon automatically creating mounts for any hostname according to the * entry, e.g. /net/foo mounting foo.example.com:/ and so on.
Your setup, with one SMB share (hopefully SMBv3 and not CIFS), could then be defined as something along the lines of:
* -fstype=smb3,credentials=/home/&/.smbcr,uid=&,fmask=0177,dmask=077 ://nas.home/&

where /nas/foo will mount //nas.home/foo with the credentials being read from /home/foo/.smbcreds and with the share only accessible by the user foo (due to the uid=, fmask=, dmask= options).

Another approach is pam_mount, which is called every time a login session is opened (whether locally or over the network).
